Given a particular problem of quantitative research, how to determine its measure space?
I understand that measure theory is the theory behind statistical modelling, which is heavily used in quantitative research. So in theory I guess there is always a way to analyze a particular problem of quantitative research in pure mathematics, but I cannot find a guideline directly connects the two. For example, if I know how IELTS scoring or corruption perceptions index works, how can I know what measure space it is?
FYI: Six Degrees of Wikipedia: from Statistical model to Measure (mathematics)

Measure theory is the formalism used to formalise what is meant by a statistical model and allow proofs to be properly formulated, just as set theory and formal logic are formalisms used to formalise much of mathematics and mathematical reasoning. If you are modelling a case where there are a finite number of possible outcomes, the measure space will typically be a finite set corresponding to the possible outcomes with a probability measure that gives the probability of each outcome. Beyond that, it is not clear what kind of answer you are looking for.

The answer that explain why all qualitative research problems have finite number of possible outcomes, and what typical measure spaces there are would be a start.

I don't buy that "all qualitative research problems have finite number of possible outcomes". Putting that aside, do you know how a probability measure on a finite set looks like?

@KurtG. That was a bad statement I agree. Perhaps "how to determine whether a problem has finite possible outcomes" is better. Admittedly I don't know how a probability measure on a finite set looks like. I haven't had much understanding on measure theory, and I know if I had known it the question would be better. I hope this would me save more time on researching. I have read functional analysis, and that's how I know about measure theory via spectral theory.

If we needed measure theory on a finite set the giants like Laplace, de Moivre, Bernoulli and so on could not get anywhere centuries ago. Hint: distribute probabilities over the finite set such that they sum to one. Lastly, the question if a problem has finite outcomes is anything but a math question.

I'll write this as an answer rather than another comment.
If there is a finite number of possible outcomes, eg a score of 1 to 5 or a yes/no answer, then a probability distribution is simply an assignment of a probability to each possible outcome so that the probabilities are non-negative and sum to 1.
Example: If the outcome is a score of 1 to 5, a probability distribution is just numbers $p_1,\ldots,p_5\ge0$ so that $\sum_i p_i=1$ where $p_i$ represents the probability of outcome $i$. Expressed as a measure space, this is the set $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and the measure $P$ defined for any $U\subset X$ as $P(U)=\sum_{i\in U} p_i$.
In a statistical model, we have a family of such distributions that depend on a parameter: ie $P_\theta$ is the same as having probabilities $p_{\theta,i}$ for $i=1,\ldots,5$ in the above example.
However, if the outcomes are real numbers, we may rather use a probability density $f(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ which just means that $f(x)\ge0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=1$. In this case, the probability of an outcome between $a$ and $b$ for $a<b$ is $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$. In this case, the measure space is $X=\mathbb{R}$ with $P([a,b])=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$. The definition $P(U)$ may be extended to more general sets $U\subset\mathbb{R}$, eg unions of intervals and most other sets that we would be interested in, but not to all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.
As you may note, in neither of these to cases is measure theory needed: you can mostly do perfectly well with either probability distributions $p_i$ for the finite (or discrete) case, or probability densities $f(x)$ in the continuous case.
However, measure theory provides a unified approach that cover both of these and more, and so provides a good theoretical basis.
